# Does Spring @transaction work on a concrete method of abstract class

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

From spring reference doc

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact that Java
>   annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies (proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect (mode="aspectj"), then the transaction settings are not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

Though it only talks about interfaces, abstract classes are considered as non-concrete as well.

So if i have an abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseService{
//here is a concrete method
@Transactional
public void updateData{
//do stuff using dao layer
}
```

and a concrete class which extends the class

```
public class SpecialService extends BaseService{
//body of class
}
```

Now if i call `specialService.updateData()` from my controller class will it be transactional?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: When I tried @Transactional on an abstract class. Spring reported a different error: A component required a bean of type 'mypackage.ActivityService' that could not be found. As soon as I uncomment the Transactional annotation from the abstract class, it is ok.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Granting that you have actually configured Spring transaction management correctly, using `@Transactional` on an abstract superclass **will** work, since `@Transactional` is itself annotated with `@Inherited` and from it's [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) we have:

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited. If an
>   Inherited meta-annotation is present on an annotation type
>   declaration, and the user queries the annotation type on a class
>   declaration, and the class declaration has no annotation for this
>   type, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for
>   the annotation type. This process will be repeated until an annotation
>   for this type is found, or the top of the class hierarchy (Object) is
>   reached. If no superclass has an annotation for this type, then the
>   query will indicate that the class in question has no such annotation.
>
> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that
>   this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from
>   superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

To actually see that `@Transactional` is annotated with `@Inherited` check out it's [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html?is-external=true)